# ¿Cómo puedo aplicar los cambios directamente con sed?

Tags: sed

Tengo varios txt en un path, estos txt tienen varios saltos de línea, y yo quiero que cada uno de ellos sea una única línea. Usando

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' /home/.../*.txt
```

imprime en la terminal lo que yo quiero, pero el archivo en cuestión no recibe los cambios. ¿Cómo puedo aplicar los cambios directamente a todos esos archivos?

Lo he intentando especificando un único archivo, haciendo lo siguiente

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' /home/.../0.txt > /home/idoia/.../0.txt
```

y al volver a abrir **0.txt**, este estaba vacío.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces

```
sed '...' fichero > fichero
```

Debes tener en cuenta cómo funcionan las redirecciones: primero hace la parte de `> fichero`, por lo que primero está truncando el fichero. De ahí que cuando hace `sed 'bla'` se encuentre con un fichero vacío.

Como comenta Adrián en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/399342/83), una solución es usar `sed -i`:

```
sed -i '...' fichero
```

Lo que hace esto es `sed '...' fichero > fichero_temporal` y luego `mv fichero_temporal fichero`.

Es recomendable guardar un fichero de backup al hacer esto:

```
sed -i.bak '...' fichero
```

Este comando copiará el contenido de "fichero" en "fichero.bak" y el fichero modificado será "fichero". Funciona tanto en GNU sed como en BSD (Mac).

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar el parámetro `-i` para editar el fichero en lugar de imprimir en pantalla.

Si el comando a usar es el siguiente:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' /home/.../*.txt
```

Entonces tendrás que hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' /home/.../*.txt
```

Comment: De acuerdo, perfecto! Gracias